# How to get a dictionary value in nested json in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, json, dataframe, dictionary, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe. One of the columns  has json value with a structure like this:

```
+-------------------+
|     col             |
+-------------------+
|{"sky":"blue","fields": {"apple":"red", "grass":[{"sun":yellow","height":{"Dad":"180","Mom":"165"}]}}         |
+-------------------+
```

So basically it's a column with nested dictionary/json value.How can I retrieve the value of "Mom" and append it to a new column for every record?

Comment: the type of `col` is string ?

Comment: @Steven yes strings